# working with multiple forms in same action class in Struts2

Tags: struts2

How do we populate\retrieve information from\into multiple forms in same action class in Struts2 ? With ModelDriven approach, action is tied to one form. With ScopedModelDriven interceptor jsp becomes dirty as one has to write model.property to access form properties. Is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: You mean several forms in the same JSP ? An esample ?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean, what you want to achieve and/or give an example.